# Which i should use for my View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View :

```
 <table id="cartbox">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tên hàng</th>
                    <th>Số lượng</th>
                    <th>Đơn giá</th>
                    <th colspan="2" style="width:70px">Thành tiền</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>@line.Product.Name
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">@Html.DropDownList("Quantity", new SelectList(ViewBag.Items as System.Collections.IList, "Value", "Text", line.Quantity))</td>
                        <td style="color:#3A9504;margin-left:3px" class="price">@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", line.Product.Price)</td>
                        <td class="subtotal">@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", (line.Quantity * line.Product.Price))</td>
                        <td align="center" style="width:10px"><a href="@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Cart",new{ProID= line.Product.ProductID, returnUrl= Request.Url.PathAndQuery})"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete.png")" style="padding-right:10px" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#DFDFDF;border-top-width:1px;">
                    <td colspan="3" align="right" style="border-right-color:#808080;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px;text-align:right"><b>Tổng tiền:</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"><b>@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue())</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Which  jquery ajax function i should use to update subtotal & total when user change quantity on dropdownList:

```
function CalValue() {
$("#select").change(function () {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var fprice = $(this).closest("tr").find("td[class^=price]").html();
    var price = fprice.replace(/[,\s(VNĐ)]/g, '')
    var fsubtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
    var subtotal = 
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td[class^=subtotal]").html(subtotal);
});
```

}

The problem with this function is after i refresh page, the page return to orgrinal value, nothing changes.
or

```
   function UpdateValue() {
    $(document.body).on("change", ".Quantity", function () {
        var ProID = $(this).attr("data");
        var Quatity = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: "/Cart/UpdateValue",
            data: { ProID: ProID, quantity: Quatity },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#cartbox").html(data);
            }
        }
            );
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
    });
}
```

And this problem is it return a new View, but the dropdownlist is duplicated in the View.

Anyone can tell me how can i control or use which method? Please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save information on client side you have following options:

1. Send it to server and store it in session and durring view render use this information
2. Use local storage on client side and after reload check if local storage has this data and use them properly